# Power Automate Excel to Sharepoint: update item if any column in Excel table is different (not just 1 unique ID)

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, excel

[image]**Question summary: How can I update a list item if ANY value in the Excel row has changed?**

I'm somewhat familiar with Power Automate now and can figure out flows.  I want to update a Sharepoint list from an Excel file when it changes.  So I have the right triggers, get rows, etc.

Update item works with only ONE Key ID, i.e., ONE column header.  So that content of that list column is compared to the corresponding Excel table column and if they are different, the item is updated.  At least, this is my understanding.

What I'd like to do is update the item if ANY column in the Excel table has changed.  If simpler, I don't mind just over-writing the list item (even if it is identical to the table item) if that makes for easier programming. Maybe this involves making an HTTP call and parsing JSON - I'm okay with that too.

At the moment, I'm deleting the list items one by one and re-populating the entire list.  But this takes quite some time since I have close to 4000 rows.  Hoping for a better/elegant solution - and some learning in case I got it all wrong.

TIA,

Joe